# Pass form data and a parameter with Vue axios to Laravel controller

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am trying to send a file input AND one more parameter to the controller in order to upload the files.

For image / file upload I use the "vue-upload-multiple-image" plugin.

```
            <vue-upload-multiple-image
              dragText="Drop your photos here"
              browseText="(or click to upload)"
              primaryText="Default"
              markIsPrimaryText="Set as default"
              popupText="This photo will be displayed as default"
              @upload-success="uploadImageSuccess"
              @before-remove="beforeRemove"
              />
```

In Vue methods:

```
 uploadImageSuccess(formData, index, fileList) {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
    }
  }

  this.$store.dispatch('listings/addPhotos', {
    'imageData': formData,
    'config': config
  })
},
```

In vuex store I have the following:

```
  async addPhotos ({ commit }, listing) {
    await axios.post('/api/addPhotos', listing.imageData, listing.config)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data)
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  },
```

And in Laravel controller:

```
public function addPhotos(Request $request)
  {
      $imgpath = public_path('images');
      $fileName = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
      $newName = time() . '_'.$fileName.'.' . $request->file->getClientOriginalExtension();
      $request->file->move($imgpath, $newName);

      $post['name'] = $file_name;
      //$post['paired'] = 'slug';
      //$post['listing_id'] = 0;
      $result = ListingPhoto::insertGetId($post);
  }
```

This works fine. Image file is uploaded and data are also uploaded in DB.

What I can't figure out is how to use another parameter so that I can add some data in the field "paired" in database.

Lets say now I send "formData".
Is it possible to send formData AND slug?

Something like this:

```
this.$store.dispatch('listings/addPhotos', {
    'imageData': formData,
    'slug': slug,
    'config': config
  })
```

Or maybe adding it into the formdata like this:

```
let formDataN = new FormData();
formDataN.append('imgfile', formData);
formDataN.append('slug', slug);
```

I tried both ways but it returns an error.
When I send the "formDataN" (which contains the normal formData with the image AND the slug) it stops working. When I try for example to getClientOriginalName, it either says "Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null" or "Trying to get property 'file' of non-object"

Can anyone help me with this? Any suggestions of how to do this?
I just want to use the formData as I normally do BUT also send another parameter "slug" to add in the database table.

---

**EDIT:
I found a way of doing this but I feel this is not the best solution.
Anyway, for anyone interested:**

```
uploadImageSuccess(formData, index, fileList) {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
    }
  }

  let slug = 'slug-uid-'+this.user.id

  this.$store.dispatch('listings/addPhotos', {
    'imageData': formData,
    'slug': slug,
    'config': config
  })
},
```

in vuex store:

```
  async addPhotos ({ commit }, listing) {
    await axios.post(`/api/addPhotos/${listing.slug}`, listing.imageData, listing.config)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data)
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  },
```

in API call:

```
Route::post('addPhotos/{slug}', 'ListingController@addPhotos');
```

And in the controller:

```
public function addPhotos($slug, Request $request)
  {
    ...
```

---

**EDIT2:
I just realised the vue upload image plugin I am using, it already creates a "formData" so I didn't have to create a new one in my Vue code. So what I need to do is to just append any other parameter I want. Final solution:**

```
uploadImageSuccess(formData, index, fileList) {    
  let slug = 'slug-uid-'+this.user.id
  formData.append("slug", slug);

  this.$store.dispatch('listings/addPhotos', formData)
},
```

In order to retrieve the actual image file, you use "file" (this is how it is defined in the vue-upload-multiple-image plugin). In laravel controller:

```
$request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
$request->slug;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if it helps

Rather sending formdata and slug to vuex attach slug to formData like that

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("image", image); // this should be your image
formData.append("slug", slug); // it is the slug

this.$store.dispatch('listings/addPhotos', formData)
```

In vuex:

```
  async addPhotos ({ commit }, formData) {
    await axios.post('/api/addPhotos', formData, {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'})
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data)
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  },
```

In Laravel:

```
public function addPhotos(Request $request)
  {
      $img = $request->file('image');
      $slug = $request->slug;
  }
```

Comment: I tried this but it says ""Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null". Thanks for the reply

Comment: Check if you are sending file correctly   ```const image = e.target.files[0];```  and then  ```formData.append("image", image);```  I did it in my last project and mine works fine

Comment: I am using a Vue upload image plugin so it's a bit different from what you are describing. But when you say to append the image, you mean the image path?

Comment: Never mind, i just made it working. The plugin was already appending image in a formdata. And your post helps me figuring it out and writing the correct code in Laravel which is $request->file('file') in my case. Thx